# How do I cut a string in TCL?

Tags: tcl

Hello I am trying to cut a string in my script and set them to two different variables in my script.

```
date_string = "OCT-09-1956"
```

What I want to do is take that date_string variable above and split it into two different variables a month variable and a year variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some may tell you that `regexp` is the solution here.

I recommend using the `split` command to create a new list and then assign new variables from the list elements.  I like to avoid regexes unless they're really necessary.

```
set date_string "OCT-09-1956"
lassign [split $date_string "-"] month day year
puts "The month is $month"
puts "The year is $year"
```